# How to make a callable BottomNavigationBar that shows in home after user login

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a verification user and navigate it to home screen. Then I want to show `BottomNavigationBar` inside the app after login, so I created `BottomNavigationBar` within a callable widget so I can call it inside every page. I don't want to use `CurvedNavigationBar` and try to use `BottomNavigationBar` without routes. Should I use routes?

This is my code that works with main.dart but won't work if I change it into another widget. I get the Items is not defined and don't know why.

```dart
// import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

import '../page/group_screen.dart';
import '../page/home_screen.dart';
import '../page/post_screen.dart';
import '../page/profile_screen.dart';
import '../page/search_screen.dart';

class BottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<BottomNavigationBar> createState() => _BottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarState extends State<BottomNavigationBar> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final screens = [
    HomePage(),
    SearchPage(),
    Post(),
    Group(),
    Profile(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(index: currentIndex, children: screens),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          fixedColor: Colors.black,
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Home',
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              label: 'Search',
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              label: 'Post',
              icon: Icon(Icons.post_add),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              label: 'Group',
              icon: Icon(Icons.group),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              label: 'Profile',
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: currentIndex,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = index;
            });
          },
        ),
      );
}
```

Here are the error messages:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are naming the widget `BottomNavigationBar`  which is the default(same name) widget provided by Flutter.

Change your class name to something else like

```dart
class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget { //this class name
  @override
  State<MyBottomNavigationBar> createState() => _MyBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _MyBottomNavigationBarState extends State<MyBottomNavigationBar> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final screens = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          fixedColor: Colors.black,
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
```